# Is ghrelin only secreted when the stomach is empty?

Tags: metabolism, endocrinology, digestion, stomach, blood-sugar

Several texts indicate that ghrelin is secreted when the stomach is empty. However, some(not all) texts also indicate that ghrelin is secreted when blood sugar levels are low. Is the second statement true? If so, how does it relate to the first statement?

Consider a hypothetical situation:A person drinks water at regular intervals such that his/her stomach is sufficiently full throughout the day.During this period he doesn’t eat and his blood sugar level is low. Would ghrelin be released at any point in such a situation(excluding the night)?